# Autodocumentation for C# code hosted online

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

Is there a service like [ReadTheDocs](https://readthedocs.org/) that allows you to automatically create documentation for C# code (from GitHub repo, for example) and host it on this service?

I've tried ReadTheDocs and it seems it's for Python only.

Comment: [Try.Net](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/creating-interactive-net-documentation/) 
Something like this?

Comment: No, Try.Net is a tool to **make your code inside Markdown files runnable**. I need a tool to generate docs from XML comments and host it online.

Comment: I see I understand, it seems like you may need specialist solution. I have used CAKE in the past to convert my mark downs inside code to be output as HTML and deployed those but that may not be enough for you either. Have a read of [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/addins/markdown/). Its a really powerful tool that allows you to run build actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Sandcastle in the past: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/wiki

Builds MS style documentation. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Yes, MS style doc iswhat I need. Does Sandcastle produce offline help file or hosts it somewhere on the web?

Comment: It builds a second "web app" that in the few times I've used it I just hosted alongside my deployed API. I'll admit to being far from an expert  user.